# How to automatically add a shortcut for removable media on Windows desktop, like some Linux distros?

Tags: windows, desktop, shortcuts, removable-media

I use sometimes some Linux distros, e.g. Ubuntu, and I like the feature they have to add a desktop shortcut to every removable device that is plugged in on desktop - for example, when a DVD is inserted, a new icon for that appears on desktop, and with that I can access, eject etc.

I would like to have the same feature for Windows - specifically for Windows XP Professional SP3, but it is interesting to know the solution for other Windows versions...

Any help?

PS1:
I would like to have "dynamic shortcuts", i.e, shortcutes that appears on desktop when the removable device is inserted and that disappears when it is removed.

PS2:
I'm talking about CD/DVD media and massive storage devices mainly.

Comment: After I saw it, I agree...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 7 (and I assume this works in XP) you can place a shortcut on your desktop to the CDROM drive; the downside is that this icon doesn't update when you insert a drive (but it does allow direct access to the drive).

You could also consider the [DeskDrive tool](http://mike-ward.net/deskdrive/) - I haven't tried it, but it looks like it will do what you want.  It's also more dynamic than the native shortcut method.

Comment: guy, i wanna to do that dynamic way to show it only when it is there, not a static shortcut, got it? i'll test the suggested software...

Comment: that DeskDrive tool is so cool!!!!

Comment: But a little buggy, so I abandoned it :/